A film about an evil/possessed piano that kills people and eats cats
I've been looking for this film/TV episode's name for years with no luck, even though people have given many suggestions. Film came out in the late 80s or early 90s. I believe it was a bit comic, but it wasn't overwhelming. 
I actually found the following description of the film on another forum:
It was about a possessed piano. All I remember about it is, the main character gets his hands crushed/broken at some point and the piano plays for him at a school function. A guy who is bullying him goes to destroy the piano at night, but the piano kills him by repeatedly slamming him into a wall. The piano also eats the main characters' cat at some point, as his parents find the cats collar inside the piano. The main character dies towards the end of the film and his parents take the piano to an antiques shop, where a little girl starts playing the piano and then discovers that it can play things itself. Then the credits started to roll.
It's not:

The Demons of Ludlow
House (1977) - Japanese horror
Tales from the Darkside - the satanic piano


I was going to say Hausu (AKA House) (1977).

Not TftDS: The Satantic Piano; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJM_m3OUDHE

Not: Torture Garden, Act 3: Mr Steinway; https://youtu.be/m9eawYp9oLU?si=cs3jtP_BTr3GA-5q&t=4114
